# Custom control development in iOS

Tags: ios

Is there a guide / book about custom control development for iOS? All the books I've found don't go beyond using UIKit builtin controls.

Comment: Don't know of any book, but a few good resources online by looking through open source code; e.g.: http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls

Comment: Thanks for the link! So UIView seems to be the starting point from what I understand from the source codes.

Comment: Havent seen one focused on that and I have 71 books. I learnt in SO, reading source in Cocoa Controls, and in weblog posts (see http://idevrecipes.com/, http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/12/uitableview-construction-drawing-and.html). Most times is just pasting stuff you already know (custom segmented control = view + buttons), others you subclass the superclass and reimplement the methods (UITableViewController), some features are complicated to implement though.

Comment: GitHub is great generally; always trying out demo projects just to play-around with ideas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @petert wrote, [Cocoa Controls](http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls) is a great resource, but my favourite is by far [iDev Recipes](http://idevrecipes.com/) (even though it's not updating that often anymore). Check also http://maniacdev.com/, many open source libraries/projects can be found and it gets updated regularly. Ray Wenderlich has also many nice tutorials - scroll down to "[Graphics and Animation](http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials)".

EDIT: I just saw that @Jano suggests idevrecipes as well, sorry for doulbe posting